# Insert into database using data manipulation API-Moodle

Tags: php, database, moodle

I'm trying to insert data into my database when the user clicks on the Save button but i'm getting this error message:

> A required parameter (name) was missing
>
> More information about this error

```
Debug info: 
Error code: missingparam
Stack trace:
line 463 of \lib\setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 548 of \lib\moodlelib.php: call to print_error()
line 8 of \local\try\process.php: call to required_param()
```

Here's the part of the codes from the form:

```
<?php
$table = new html_table();
$table->data[] = array("Faculty ID", "<input type='text' name='facid' size='60'");
$table->data[] = array("Faculty Name", "<input type='text' name='name' size='60'");
$table->data[] = array("Comment", "<input type='text' name='comment' size='60'");

echo html_writer::table($table);
?>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type='button' onClick="location='index.php'" value="Back"/>&nbsp; <input type='button' value='Save' onClick="location='process.php'"/>
</div>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

global $DB;

$id = optional_param('facid', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$name = required_param('name', PARAM_TEXT);
$comment = required_param('comment', PARAM_TEXT);

$record1 = new stdClass();
$record1->name  = $id;
$record1->displayorder = '10000';

$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name  = $name;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';

$record3 = new stdClass();
$record3->name = $comment;
$record3->displayorder = '10000';

// Insert one record at a time.
$lastinsertid1 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record1);
$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);
$lastinsertid3 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record3);

if(!$lastinsertid)
{
    echo "Could not insert";
}
else
{
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'save' button does not submit any of the data in your form, it just changes the browser URL to 'process.php'.

If you want to process the data, you need to wrap it all in a form and add an input of type 'submit' to the end of it (although, if you're using Moodle, you should really use the Moodle Form API instead).